# Mist wallet; Forgotten password

Tags: mist, wallets, password

Made a mist wallet put ethereum into it and stupidly forgot my password. Have I lost my eth, or if I still have control of the private keys for the eth can I recover it elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's gone, your keyfile is useless without the password.